# Typescript Mongoose get IntelliSense or Warnings for Schema fields in VS Code

Tags: typescript, mongoose, visual-studio-code

I want to set-up a code completion for my Mongoose Models.

So if i create a new Model i´d like to see the available fields which are defined in my Mongoose Schema. Also errors/warnings by the compiler, that not all fields are provided would be nice

Simple Example

```
//define Schema
const MyUserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    firstname: String,
    password: String
})

//create Model
export const MyUserModel = model('user', MyUserSchema)

//instance of MyUserModel
let testUser = new MyUserModel({
    //want IntelliSense for fields here
    name: "Lastname",
    firstname: "Firstname",
    password: "securepassword"
}):
```

I think somehow i have to use Interfaces. But i cant figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [the Mongoose `Model` type accepts `any` in its constructor](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5344bfc80508c53a23dae37b860fb0c905ff7b24/types/mongoose/index.d.ts#L2521). As a result, you will not receive compiler errors for missing fields.

That said, the following will achieve part of what you require:

```
import { Document, Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

interface User {
    name: String,
    firstname: String,
    password: String
}

interface UserModel extends User, Document { }

const MyUserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    firstname: String,
    password: String,
})

export const MyUserModel = model<UserModel>('user', MyUserSchema)

let testUser = new MyUserModel({
    name: 'foo',
    firstname: 'bar',
    password: 'baz'
});
```

With the above setup, when you dot into `testUser` you will see `name`, `firstname`, and `password` in the intellisense.

Comment: Youre right. With that i get suggestions when i do `testUser.firstname`. This already helps a lot! But when defining the new model `let testUser=new MyUserModel()` i dont´t get suggestions there. Is there a way to extend the Model class of mongoose or something to also achieve that?

Comment: I have to define the user 3 times. GraphQL, Mongoose & TypeScript. It sucks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using TypeScript and JS environment, you have ability to make some changes in d.ts files for achieve autocomplete when creating model.

1. Go to `node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts`
2. Find definition of `Model` (2881 line in @types/mongoose=5.5.34)
3. Make some changes

from

```js
    new(doc?: any): T;
```

to

```js
    new(doc?: Omit<T, keyof Document>): T;
```

[image: autocomplete working :)]

Comment: is there any other way to do this without changing mongoose definition file?

Comment: Only approved PullRequest to type-definition library of mongoose

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly how you are expecting. But there is a workaround available if you only want to get intellisense. I feel this is what you require.

```js
//Define interface
interface User {
  name: String;
  firstname: String;
  password: String;
}

interface UserModel extends User, mongoose.Document {}

//define Schema
const MyUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  firstname: String,
  password: String,
});

//create Model
export const MyUserModel = mongoose.model<UserModel>('user', MyUserSchema);

let input: Partial<UserModel> = {
  //Get your intellisense here
  name: 'Lastname',
  firstname: 'Firstname',
  password: 'securepassword',
};

//instance of MyUserModel
let testUser = new MyUserModel(input);

testUser.firstname //get your intellisense here as well
```